# Stack Exchange userscript for showing spoilers on questions with particular tags

Tags: javascript, stackexchange, userscript

Stack Exchange sites support hiding text as a spoiler with `>!`; for example:

> This text will be hidden until you hover over it/tap the "show spoiler" button.

This gets a lot of use on the Sci-Fi & Fantasy stack, usually to cover up key plot elements of a particular work (like the recent *Star Wars* film).

That’s a good way to avoid spoilers if you haven’t seen the work in question, but it can be annoying if you already know the plot.  Over on [Meta SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7888/3567), somebody asked whether it would be possible to unhide spoilers on questions with particular tags.

I wrote this UserScript, which allows the user to specify an array of tags, and will unhide spoilers on questions with those tags:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SFF.SE Show spoilers on questions with particular tags
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.0
// @description  Show all spoilers on SFF.SE questions with specified tags
// @author       alexwlchan
// @match         *://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match         *://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';


// If every tag on a question is in this array, then the spoilers on this
// question will be shown.
var SHOW_ME_SPOILERS_IF_TAGGED = [
    "harry-p0tter",
    "star-w4rs",
];


// Returns an array of tags on a question
var getTagsOnQuestion = function() {
    var taglist = document.getElementsByClassName("post-taglist")[0];
    var hrefs = taglist.getElementsByClassName("post-tag");

    var tags = [];
    for (var ii = 0; ii < hrefs.length; ii++) {
        tags.push(hrefs[ii].innerText);
    }
    return tags;
}


// Returns true/false depending on whether the spoilers on this question
// should be shown -- that is, whether every tag on the question is in
// SHOW_ME_SPOILERS_IF_TAGGED.
var shouldShowSpoilersOnQuestion = function() {

    // Get the tags on a question.  All questions have at least one tag.
    var tags = getTagsOnQuestion();

    for (var jj = 0; jj < tags.length; jj++) {
        // If we don't find the tag in the array of spoiler-able tags,
        // then we have to reject the question.
        if (SHOW_ME_SPOILERS_IF_TAGGED.indexOf(tags[jj]) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


// Modify all the spoilers on the page to show their spoiler text
var showSpoilers = function() {
    var spoilers = document.getElementsByClassName("spoiler");
    for (var kk = 0; kk < spoilers.length; kk++) {
        spoilers[kk].transition = "none";
        spoilers[kk].style.color = "#222426";
    }
}


if (shouldShowSpoilersOnQuestion()) {
    showSpoilers();
}
```

Any feedback is welcome, but particularly:

- Is this good/idiomatic JavaScript?
- Is the intent of the code clear?
- Are there any edge cases that I’ve missed?
- Is there a better way to check if (tags on the question) is a subset of (tags the user wants spoilers to be shown for)? I feel like my current approach is quite inefficient.

Comment: Stupid question: if I were to open a chrome window of a stack exchange question and run this in the console (which I can't right now since I'm on mobile) would this script actually reveal spoilers with the tag Star Wars or no?

Comment: @AshwinGupta It should reveal spoilers with the tag "star-wars", although the recent questions ~should be tagged with "the-force-awakens" as well. To be safe, I've tweaked the tags in the example.

Comment: cool I am going to study that code now :D. I have always wanted to learn how to do cool/useful stuff like that in JS. I actually initially learnt programmed in JS but I stopped once I got to like Objects and stuff and learned Java. Now I'm learning Python and Java but I'm tempted to jump back into JavaScript and maybe also jump into C# since the UNity game engine is so cool.

Answer (score 3):

### For Loop

The style of the `for` loop you're using could be improved.

```
for (var jj = 0; jj < tags.length; jj++) {
    // If we don't find the tag in the array of spoiler-able tags,
    // then we have to reject the question.
    if (SHOW_ME_SPOILERS_IF_TAGGED.indexOf(tags[jj]) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

should probably be changed to a [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```
for (tag of tags) {
    // If we don't find the tag in the array of spoiler-able tags,
    // then we have to reject the question.
    if (SHOW_ME_SPOILERS_IF_TAGGED.indexOf(tag) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### map

This code is essentially doing the same thing as a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
var tags = [];
for (var ii = 0; ii < hrefs.length; ii++) {
    tags.push(hrefs[ii].innerText);
}
```

You could rewrite it to this (which uses an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as well):

```
var tags = hrefs.map(href => href.innerText);
```

Answer (score 3):

> He's actually his father

Jokes aside, your code is good, but there's a few things it could use to make it great:

---

## Using the right levels of abstraction and user control:

> ```
> var SHOW_ME_SPOILERS_IF_TAGGED = [
>     "harry-p0tter",
>     "star-w4rs",
> ];
> ```

I'm not trying to insult, but I would think that some of the SF&F community aren't actually programmers, and as such, they may have issues or reservations modifying this.

I would suggest implementing a dialog box that pops up the first time you run the script, and using a drag-and-drop list (so they can choose tags). For this, you could use a plugin like [jQuery UI's Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

---

## Using `map`:

You don't need to build an array using another variable, you can just convert and use `Array.prototype.map`:

> ```
> var taglist = document.getElementsByClassName("post-taglist")[0];
> var hrefs = taglist.getElementsByClassName("post-tag");
> var tags = [];
> for (var ii = 0; ii < hrefs.length; ii++) {
>     tags.push(hrefs[ii].innerText);
> }
> return tags;
> ```

into:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("post-taglist")[0]
           .getElementsByClassName("post-tag");
return Array.prototype.slice.apply(tags).map(function(e){
    return e.innerText;
});
```

or using arrow notation:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("post-taglist")[0]
           .getElementsByClassName("post-tag");
return Array.prototype.slice.apply(tags).map(e => e.innerText);
```

---

## Naming:

### Index variables:

Your choice of naming on your index variables is strange:

- `jj`, `ii`, `kk`

They can never exist at the same time, so it's pretty pointless to have them named differently. You should just stick with the standard index variable name: `i`.

### `SHOW_ME_SPOILERS_IF_TAGGED`:

This is a bit long and *icky*, I would consider smaller names like `SPOILABLE`, `SPOILABLE_TAGS`, `TAGS_TO_SPOIL` or something similar instead.

---

## `spoiler` class:

Instead of modifying the style properties on each spoiler, you can just take away the spoiler class.

> ```
> var spoilers = document.getElementsByClassName("spoiler");
> for (var kk = 0; kk < spoilers.length; kk++) {
>     spoilers[kk].transition = "none";
>     spoilers[kk].style.color = "#222426";
> }
> ```

into:

```
var spoilers = document.getElementsByClassName("spoiler");
for (var i = 0; i < spoilers.length; i++) {
    spoilers[i].classList.remove('spoiler');
}
```

However, this code would have an issue as you're accessing a live-list and removing it from that would effective mean that you'd skip every second data item, up to the last item would be skipped entirely.

Instead, select all `<blockquotes>` tags, like:

```
var spoilers = document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote");
for (var i = 0; i < spoilers.length; i++) {
    spoilers[i].classList.remove('spoiler');
}
```

---

## L33T:

I'm not sure why you guys over at SF&F would have tags like:

- `harry-p0tter`, or
- `star-w4rs`.

Either this a bug, or you should just be commenting out those lines instead of confusing the reader.